# DateTime.Now retrieval speed

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any chance that this statement would return true

```
DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now
```

can a very fast machine return true for this statement, I tried on several machines and its always false ?

Comment: I tried this on DotNetFiddle and it returns true

Comment: @Tuco Have you tried on real .NET application ?

Comment: DotNetFiddle runs real .NET

Comment: It's true more often than not

Comment: Even a slow machine can do this. `DateTime` does not have near the resolution to make it even close to unique.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes.

> The resolution of this property depends on the system timer, which is
>   approximately 15 milliseconds on Windows systems.As a result, repeated
>   calls to the Now property in a short time interval, such as in a loop,
>   may return the same value.

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8):

I just ran this script in LINQPad:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(i => DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now).ToList()
```

After the first element, all the others are true. I'm guessing there's some latency involved in the first couple of calls to `DateTime.Now` which causes the check to often return false the first time you run it in a given application.

But yes, that expression can (and often does) return true.